# paste is disabled on QlineEdit using PyQt

Tags: qt, pyqt, paste, qlineedit

I made a simple application in PyQt for inserting data in a database. I used multiples QlineEdit and in all of them I can copy, cut, undo etc. but I cannot paste text. If I right-click on the QlineEdit 'paste' is disabled. 
Here below the code where I defined the QlineEdit:

```
class Ui_Form(QtGui.QWidget):

def __init__(self):
    QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
    self.setupUi(self)

def setupUi(self, Dialog):
    self.titolo = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
    self.titolo.setDragEnabled(True)
    self.titolo.setReadOnly(False)
    self.titolo.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("titolo"))
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.titolo, 0, 2, 1, 1)
```

Comment: The code you have posted is not a minimilistic working example. Please make a self contained example that reproduces the behaviour.

Comment: Also, a minimilistic example I made does not produce the behaviour you report (you **can** paste text into the QLineEdit) see: http://pastebin.com/LeG8cEtH

Comment: I ran your example and I get the same problem. I cannot paste

Comment: @three_pineapples's example works for me

Comment: Can you confirm you have actually copied just text (for instance from the address bar of your browser) before trying to paste and then also versions of your OS, Python, PyQt, etc